# When a Question is Eligible to be deleted

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts

I saw today couple of questions that were asked more than a year ago. They have answers posted on them as well but neither question has any score nor answer and also OP didn't accepted the posted answer.

I think that if question didn't got any answer in so long time and that question is not helping others they should get deleted from SO.

If I am thinking right I would like to know that should we flag that post for Moderator attention or use the delete vote option?

If I am thinking wrong I would like to know when a question is eligible to be deleted?

Comment: Why do they need to be deleted?  Just because they don't have an accepted answer doesn't mean they potentially could help another user.

Comment: No in question OP didn't showed any effort himself and  sometimes even question not clear what OP is trying to ask

Comment: If there's no answer and question has zero votes, it gets autodeleted after a year anyway AFAIK.

Comment: @JonasCz :- thats totally wrong, if SO is not able to provide the answer, then delete it.....after a year

Comment: Then what is the criteria that should be kept in mind for deleting a post either it's question or answer?

Comment: @Piyush, But they [are](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) deleted after a year, providing some conditions are met.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad If the question is unclear then vote to close it and downvote it.  Closed downvoted questions will get deleted automatically if they don't have an answer with a positive score.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, Usually, you should not delete stuff, as it might be useful to others. Use your close votes and downvotes instead.

Comment: @JonasCz  yes I got your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the answers on this page: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Specifically:

> ### What are the criteria for deletion?
>
> For questions, a post that no longer adds anything to the site should
> be deleted. Basically, this includes most closed questions that cannot
> be improved and reopened. However, it may be beneficial to keep
> duplicates to aid future users in finding the canonical question.
>
> For answers, any post that is not an answer (should be a comment,
> doesn't answer the question, etc.) should be deleted. Answers that are
> wrong or that dispense poor advice should be downvoted, not deleted.

Questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59054/148099

Answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163733/148099